# Ubuntu: class Serverfireteam\blog\BlogServiceProvider not found

Tags: php, laravel, package, blogs, laravel-5

I'm using the blog package for laravel 5 that you can find [here](https://github.com/serverfireteam/blog).

After adding the servideprovider to the app.php config file i get the error:

```
Class 'Serverfireteam\blog\BlogServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 150
```

When following the same steps on a windows or mac i get no errors. What could the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't located in the app.php config file.
The namespace also isn't a problem. I had the same error for quite some time and you have to change the folder name:

```
%PROJECT_FOLDER%/vendor/serverfireteam/blog/src/Serverfireteam/Blog
```

to

```
%PROJECT_FOLDER%/vendor/serverfireteam/blog/src/Serverfireteam/blog
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it should be:

```
Serverfireteam\Blog\BlogServiceProvider
```

with capital letter for `Blog` (looking at `https://github.com/serverfireteam/blog/blob/master/src/Serverfireteam/Blog/BlogServiceProvider.php`).

The docs on `github` also contain this error.

Comment: That's not the issue. I just did a quick test installing the package and the namespace casing is not the problem.

Comment: @Bogdan Have you tested it on Linux and not in Vagrant on Windows?

Comment: Yep, I don't use Windows. I use Ubuntu 12.04 as my desktop OS :).